# How to not import commit messages when I do git merge upstream/master & git push origin

Tags: git

How to not import all the messages of upstream when I do a

```
git merge upstream/master
git push origin master
```

I just need a message "merged from upstream"

Is rebase after the push the only option?

Comment: what the fluff are git messages ? am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a merge commit (not a rebase), you can override the default commit messsage.

Option 1: Set commit message when you merge:

```
git merge upstream/master -m "Your commit message"
```

Option 2: Open up an editor when merging

```
git merge upstream/master --edit
```

Option 3: Merge without committing, then commit with your own message

```
git merge upstream/master --no-commit
git commit -m "Your commit message"
```

Third option lets you look at the merge result before actually committing. You could make further modifications if you wanted to (although I always avoid doing that, I prefer to add an extra commit after the merge).